# Size limit of my ios app particularly Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, size, limit

I have developed an app. It is an in-house app. I want to know if there is any limit on the size my app can take up on the iOS device. My app connects to a web-service and downloads data from SQL server. Maybe 1000s of rows. How much data can my app store on the iOS device? Can someone explain it in simple terms. I read its 2GB. But i think that is the size of the app when you install it.Correct? In archives section of organizer my app now says 1MB. So that 2gb, is the limit there correct?50 mb is the size of OTA download. I want to know how much space my app can occupy on the iOS Device. How much core data space can my app occupy? More questions to come. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware you have can save as much data as you want on the device until it runs out of memory. Core Data store (eg sqlite file) just lives in a file in the documents directory of the device. Once there is no more room on the device, and there are no caches to clear I assume it will throw errors 'no space available' and such.

Write a quick little app that loads a large image from the bundle and saves it to the documents folder with a different filename (timestamp?), loop it until the device crashes and you might get to see how much memory it lets you have :)

(Do it on an actual device, not the Simulator)

Answer (score 0):

2GB is the maximum size of the app that you are allowed to upload to iTunes and I don't think relates to how big your app can eventually become on the device.